# Tell Haddock to use a different base URL for hyperlinked identifiers from other packages

Tags: haddock

I'd like to host my haddock docs on my own site, but when I generate them on my machine they contain `file://` links to the values and types from `base`:

```
<a href="file:///Library/Frameworks/GHC.framework/Versions/7.10.3-x86_64/usr/share/doc/ghc/html/libraries/base-4.7.2.0/Data-Bool.html#t:Bool">Bool</a>
```

Is there a way to tell `haddock` to use a different base url for links to identifiers from outside my package?